# LOG4J Multiple Loggers in same class

Tags: database, logging, log4j

I have a java project that has a log4j logging. It uses a rolling file appender and multiple loggers to log to a file. 
I want to add a DBappender and have a seperate logger that only writes to this appender, with none of the other loggers sending messages to it. I need, say one class to have two loggers, one writing to the fileAppender and one writing to the  dbAppender. Is this possible, if so what is the configuration for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to use two `Logger`s in one class.

First idea: get the two loggers with different names:

```
package com.mycompany.apackage.MyClass;

public class MyClass {
    private static final logger = Logger.getLogger(Myclass.class)
    private static final dbLogger = Logger.
        getLogger(Myclass.class.getName() + ".dblogger")
}
```

Config for the package of the `dbLogger`:

```
<root> 
    <appender-ref ref="mainlog" /> 
</root> 

<logger name="com.mycompany.apackage.MyClass.dblogger">
    <appender-ref ref="dbappender" />
</logger>
```

(Not tested.)
In that case the `dbLogger` also logs to the `mainlog` appender. If it's not appropriate you could use
a custom filter in the `mainlog` (and other) appenders which filters out the messages of the `dbLogger`. Another solution is using a completely different prefix for the `dbLogger`:

```
    private static final logger = Logger.getLogger(Myclass.class)
    private static final dbLogger = Logger.
        getLogger("dblogger." + Myclass.class.getName())
```

Log4j config:

```
<root> 
</root> 

<logger name="com.mycompany">
    <appender-ref ref="mainlog" />
</logger>
<logger name="dblogger.com.mycompany">
    <appender-ref ref="dbappender" />
</logger>
```

Note that if you pass the same parameter to the `getLogger()` method you will get same `Logger` object, so you have to use different names.