# self4g logback two logger in same class not working

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

i use slf4j+logback
Here is logback.xml with 3 appenders (1 - console, 2 different files)

`

```
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="D:/logs" />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
   <!-- <file>D:/logs/all/all_log.txt</file>-->
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/all/all_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="CONNECT_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <!--<file>D:/logs/connect/connect_log.txt</file>-->
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/connect/connect_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<!--<logger name="connect" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONNECT_FILE"/>
</logger>-->
<logger name = "com" level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

`

and simple class:

```
package com.gitHub.xMIFx.Servlets;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by bukatinvv on 25.05.2015.
 */
@WebServlet("/main.do")
public class MainController  extends HttpServlet{
    private static final String PAGE_OK = "pages/main.jsp";
    private static final Logger lOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainController.class.getName());
    private static final Logger CONNECT_FILE_lOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("connect");
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
        req.setAttribute("User","Vlad");
        try {
            lOGGER.info("logger: forwarding");
            CONNECT_FILE_lOGGER.info("Connect-logger: forwarding");
           // if(true){throw new IOException("blad");}
            req.getRequestDispatcher(PAGE_OK).forward(req,resp);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            lOGGER.error("Exception", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            lOGGER.error("Exception", e);
        }
    }
}
```

lOGGER & CONNECT_FILE_lOGGER write info in the same file, so they are the same loggers.
Why when we calling `LoggerFactory.getLogger("connect");` we get logger with name "com", even when logger with name "connect" is not commented.
I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659348/log4j-multiple-loggers-in-same-class), but had the same situation.

logs from file all_log.2015-05-28.log:

```
4968 [http-nio-8081-exec-5] INFO  c.g.xMIFx.Servlets.MainController - logger: forwarding 
4968 [http-nio-8081-exec-5] INFO  connect - Connect-logger: forwarding
```

Comment: First your config is wrong: it has 'loger' tags instead of 'logger', both on connect and com loggers. Second, what do you mean by 'same loggers'? 'connect' and 'com' would be different loggers - if the configuration was right.

Comment: 1. Thank you, I changed tag 'loger' to 'logger'. But situaion not changed. 2. They write info in the same file, so they use same appenders, so they are same logger, becouse only in one logger i set 'FILE' appender

Comment: no, it doesn't work :( edit my up comment

Comment: Grasshopper, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, logback will create a logger even if you have no logger declared with the name you pass to LoggerFactory. Therefore:

- When 'connect' was commented out CONNECT_FILE_lOGGER was a ROOT child logger which also logged to the console.
- By uncommenting 'connect' you created a logger which appended to the desired file. As the additivity flag is false, any message logged to it is not propagated to its parents.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I don't know what was that. But when I added `additivity="false"` to the logger with name "com" it works. Then I returned it back and uncommented "connect" - now it all works fine.